# Picasa Web Albums API : No effect of start-index in photos feed

Tags: python, google-api, gdata, picasa

I am fetching users [recently uploaded photos](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#ListRecentPhotos) from Picasa. As mentioned in the [parameters doc.](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference#Parameters), you can paginate the response using *max-results* and *start-index* combination. But that doesn't seem to be working.

Example requests with different start-index :

https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/myEmailId?kind=photo&max-results=5&alt=json&start-index=1&imgmax=d

https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/myEmailId?kind=photo&max-results=5&alt=json&start-index=6&imgmax=d

Both the request returns the same result. There is no effect of start-index.

I have posted this on [GData Issues](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=864), but didn't get any reply yet.

Code snippet that I am trying:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PEM_FILE_PATH, "rb").read(),
      scope=["https://picasaweb.google.com/data/"],
      prn=userEmail
    )
PHOTOS_URL = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/%s?kind=photo&max-results=5&alt=json&start-index=%s&imgmax=d"
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
response, albumPhotos = http.request(PHOTOS_URL %(userEmail, startIndex), 'GET')
albumPhotos = eval(albumPhotos)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the API is seriously broken right now

Comment: Api is still broken (

Answer (score 0):

Try it in https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground.

The start-index parameter does not work on retrieving most recent updated photos from user `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/%s?kind=photo`, although the returning result indicates that openSearch:startIndex did takes the start-index parameter.

But it will work if you query for the photos inside a particular album, e.g:
`https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/{albmId}?start-index=10`

Comment: Even so... you can not download more than 10.000 photos this way.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `gphoto$numphotos` value (`response['feed']['entry']['gphoto$numphotos']`). After retrieving the value you can use:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/{albmId}?start-index=VALUE
```